# Python struct to convert int to IEEE float

Tags: python, struct, lambda

I implemented two lambda functions using struct

```
int_to_float = lambda n: struct.unpack('@f', struct.pack('@I', n))[0]
float_to_int = lambda f: struct.unpack('@I', struct.pack('@f', f))[0]
```

Then I test:

```
f1 = 1.90826472023605
i = float_to_int(f1)
f2 = int_to_float(i)
print(f1, f2, i)
print(f1-f2)
```

The print results are:

```
1.90826472023605   1.9082647562026978   1072972293
-3.596664766014612e-08
```

Does this means **struct** has an issue of pack/unpack?

Comment: A word of advice, don't use `lambda` to define a function with a name.  It works, but it's not considered good form.

Comment: The accuracy of a float is limited. The difference you see may be due to the fact that Python's native float has more significant digits than `f` provides. Try again with `d`.

Answer (score 1):

You're not using enough bits to retain your original value, which is a 64-bit `double`.  Use the `d` and `Q` types instead.

```
def int_to_float(n):
    return struct.unpack('@d', struct.pack('@Q', n))[0]

def float_to_int(f):
    return struct.unpack('@Q', struct.pack('@d', f))[0]
```